# AttributeError: 'ResizeImage' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'

Tags: python, class

I'm making a class to make a nicer "thumbnail" for a picture.
The functions works fine, but inside the class I got the "object" has no "attribute 'thumbnail'". I'm not an expert on classes, but maybe a short recommendation? The "open" method worked fine!

```
class ResizeImage:
    from PIL import Image
    def newImage(self,dimensiune):
        NouaPoza = Image.new('RGBA', (dimensiune, dimensiune), (255, 255, 255, 0))
        self.thumbnail((dimensiune, dimensiune), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        coordonateCentrare = ((dimensiune - self.size[0]) // 2, (dimensiune - self.size[1]) // 2)
        NouaPoza.paste(self,coordonateCentrare)
        return NouaPoza
    def openVechi(self,fisier_in):
        self = Image.open(fisier_in)
        return self
    def saveNou(self,fisier_out):
        self.save(fisier_out)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fisier_in = "[...]"
    fisier_out = "[...]"
    poza = ResizeImage()
    poza.openVechi(fisier_in)
    poza.newImage(500)
    poza.saveNou(fisier_out)
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Working just with functions was ok, like:
    def thumbnail(poza,dimensiune):
        poza.thumbnail((dimensiune,dimensiune),Image.ANTIALIAS)

EDIT
I believe the right declaration is:

```
class ResizeImage(Image.Image):
    def newImage(self,dimensiune):
        self.thumbnail((dimensiune,dimensiune),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

BUT I get the following error:

File "C:/Users/claudiu.ivanescu/PycharmProjects/eDX/NewImage.py", line 11, in newImage
    self.thumbnail((dimensiune,dimensiune),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  File "C:\Users\claudiu.ivanescu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2059, in thumbnail
    x, y = self.size
AttributeError: 'ResizeImage' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: `self.thumbnail((dimensiune, dimensiune), Image.ANTIALIAS)` is attempting to call the method `thumbnail` that is defined in the class `ResizeImage`.  But there is no such method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching I renounce to make the class as before. I put all the details as attributes for object. And all the other method I access them without args.

There is the new class:

```
class resizeImage:
    def __init__(self,dimension,fileIn,fileOut)
        [...]
    def createThumbnail(self):
        from PIL import Image
        picture = Image.open(self.fileIn)
        [...]
        thumbnail.save(self.fileOut)
    def delThumbnail(self):
        import os,sys
        os.remove(self.fileOut)
```

Maybe will be useful for some people!